# echo contents of file into a curl command

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to run a curl command something like below:

```
curl -X POST "https://$CLUSTER/api/internal/vmware/vm/snapshot/$snapshot_id/restore_files" -H "accept: application/json" -H "authorization: "$authType" "$hash_password"" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"destObjectId\": \"$vm_id\", \"restoreConfig\": [ echo $(cat suhas_file.txt) ], \"shouldUseAgent\": true, \"shouldRestoreXAttrs\": true}" -k -s
```

I get `Request Malformed`

Due to the `echo $(cat suhas_file.txt)`

If I run this echo command manually I get:

```
echo $(cat suhas_file.txt)
{\"path\": \"C:\\\\bootmgr\"},{\"path\": \"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\desktop.ini\"}
```

If I paste this manually instead of echo in the above curl like

```
curl -X POST "https://$CLUSTER/api/internal/vmware/vm/snapshot/$snapshot_id/restore_files" -H "accept: application/json" -H "authorization: "$authType" "$hash_password"" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"destObjectId\": \"$vm_id\", \"restoreConfig\": [ {\"path\": \"C:\\\\bootmgr\"},{\"path\": \"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\desktop.ini\"} ], \"shouldUseAgent\": true, \"shouldRestoreXAttrs\": true}" -k -s
```

It works.

I tried

```
value=`cat suhas_file.txt`
```

And then `echo $value` inside the curl and I still get malformed request.

How can i basically echo the contents of this file that we see above within the `[]` of curl

Comment: Just remove `echo` from either option.

Comment: You mean something like `cat suhas_file.txt` (within \`) or `$value` right? That fails too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```sh
printf -v data '
    {
        "destObjectId": "%s",
        "restoreConfig": [%s],
        "shouldUseAgent": true,
        "shouldRestoreXAttrs": true
    }
' "$vm_id" "$(< suhas_file.txt)"

curl -X POST \
    -H "accept: application/json" \
    -H "authorization: $authType $hash_password"" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d "$data" \
    -k -s \
    "https://$CLUSTER/api/internal/vmware/vm/snapshot/$snapshot_id/restore_files"
```

Added line continuations for readability.

In the `suhas_file.txt` file, **do not escape the double quotes** -- it should be plain JSON data.

`$(< filename)` is a bash construct, equivalent to `$(cat filename)`. See [3.5.4 Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) in the manual

Comment: Thanks for the insight. So mainly the escape of double quotes was the culprit.

Comment: Yes. However, do not ignore the importance of writing readable & maintainable code.

Answer (score 0):

To safely compose a dynamic JSON data-set from a shell script, a JSON-aware parser like `jq` will ensure proper formatting.

Example:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

authType='authTypeBasic'
hash_password='samplePassword'
snapshot_id='snapshot42'
vm_id='Marvin'

data="$(
  jq \
    --null-input \
    --compact-output \
    --arg VMID "$vm_id" \
    --rawfile restoreConfig suhas_file.txt \
    '{
      "destObjectId": $VMID,
      "restoreConfig": [ $restoreConfig | split("\n") ],
      "shouldUseAgent": true,
      "shouldRestoreXAttrs": true
    }'
  )"
curl \
  --request 'POST' \
  --header "Accept: application/json" \
  --header "Authorization: $authType $hash_password" \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data "$data" \
  --insecure \
  --silent \
  --url "https://$CLUSTER/api/internal/vmware/vm/snapshot/$snapshot_id/restore_files"
```